# Is there any difference in meaning between "dry up" and "break off" in the sense of stopping talking suddenly?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Is there any difference in meaning between *dry up* and *break off* in the sense of stopping talking suddenly? For example:

> I **dried up** in the meeting when the boss asked me a question.
>
> I **broke off** in the meeting when the boss asked me a question.

Comment: You normally ***break off*** from (stop doing) one thing *in order to do something else* (feasibly, to *rest; do nothing*, but that certainly doesn't suit the context here).

Answer (score 1):

*Break off from X* means to detach or disengage from X, so you can say:

> I broke off from the meeting when the boss asked me a question.

To *break off* without *from* means to bend something, causing it to physically break and separate.

> I broke off in the meeting when the boss asked me a question.

This sounds really strange because -- why would you physically be breaking something in a meeting, and what did you break anyway (the X in *break off X* doesn't usually refer to persons/people without a lot of strong overriding context).  *Breaking off from X* when X is a team works prefectly fine though.

---

> I dried up in the meeting when the boss asked me a question.

In some regions this might be idiomatic/well-used to mean "stopping talking suddenly" but I couldn't say which ones (BrE speakers might know something I as an AmE speaker do not).  IMHO this sounds like you are saying that you are literally dehydrating.

It's possible to use *dry up* figuratively, but just like water is thing that actually dries up when it rains, speech/words would be the thing that dries up when you can't talk, not yourself.  E.g.

> My ability to speak dried up in the meeting when the boss asked me a question

but even that doesn't fully work well, because *drying* is not an instananeous action, unless you explicitly say so like this:

> My ability to speak instantly dried up when the boss asked me a question.

Answer (score 0):

- **dried up** - *If you dry up when you are speaking, you stop in the middle of what you were saying, because you cannot think what to say next.* [Source](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dry-up)

> I **dried up** in the meeting when the boss asked me a question.

This would mean that you started talking, but didn't have much information or knowledge to continue your talk, so you stopped abruptly.

- **broke off** - *If you break off when you are doing or saying something, you suddenly stop doing it or saying it.* [Source](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/break-off)

> I **broke off** in the meeting when the boss asked me a question.

This doesn't really sound idiomatic. Someone breaks off when they are already in between a conversation. It wouldn't necessarily convey the meaning that you were not able to speak because of something, like lack of knowledge or nervousness. Breaking off can mainly occur during a video conference or an online mode of communication.

When your Boss has asked you a question, you would either not speak at all or speak limited words. Hence the first sentence sounds more idiomatic in this case.

Comment: _Breaking off_ when speaking normally happens because something interrupts or startles the speaker, or they have a sudden thought which affects what they are saying. "He broke off as a man rushed into the room." It would be used mainly following direct speech - we wouldn't say "I broke off in the meeting."